# Instagram API: How to get all user media?

Tags: api, instagram

In general I need to get all user media.

User has more than 250 photos.

I do `/users/1/media/recent/?access_token=...&count=250`

But it returns only 20 photos.

Maybe instagram has a limit for getting media. 
If it is, response has a pagination to solve it. 
But there are only max ID photo. How to know the first (min) ID photo to paginate it then?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You're right, the Instagram API will only return 20 images per call. So you'll have to use the pagination feature.

If you're trying to use the API console. You'll want to first allow the API console to authenticate via your Instagram login. To do this you'll want to select OAUTH2 under the Authentication dropdown.

Once Authenticated, use the left hand side menu to select the users/{user-id}/media/recent endpoint. So for the sake of this post for {user-id} you can just replace it with self. This will then use your account to retrieve information.

At a bare minimum that is what's needed to do a GET for this endpoint. Once you send, you'll get some json returned to you. At the very top of the returned information after all the server info, you'll see a pagination portion with next_url and next_max_id.

next_max_id is what you'll use as a parameter for your query. Remember max_id is the id of the image that is the oldest of the 20 that was first returned. This will be used to return images earlier than this image.

You don't have to use the max_id if you don't want to. You can actually just grab the id of the image where you'd like to start querying more images from.

So from the returned data, copy the max_id into the parameter max_id. The request URL should look something like this https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent?max_id=XXXXXXXXXXX where XXXXXXXXXXX is the max_id. Hit send again and you should get the next 20 photos.

From there you'll also receive an updated max_id. You can then use that again to get the next set of 20 photos until eventually going through all of the user's photos.

What I've done in the project I'm working on is to load the first 20 photos returned from the initial recent media request. I then, assign the images with a data-id (-id can actually be whatever you'd like it to be). Then added a load more button on the bottom of the photo set.

When the button is clicked, I use jQuery to grab the last image and it's data-id attribute and use that to create a get call via ajax and append the results to the end of the photos already on the page. Instead of a button you could just replace it to have a infinite scrolling effect.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thx, I did it. I didn't check it right for now but in the may of this year I have been got just first 20 elements even if I set maxID or minID.

Comment: is this feature deleted from instagram API ? now i can't get more than 20 images from authenticated user

Comment: I'm trying this as well, and the pagination attribute of the response is empty, so I'd assume it is no longer possible to pull in the user's entire feed. As the endpoint's name suggests, it is called 'recent', so it looks like we are now just getting the most recent posts. I'm still looking for a solution.

Comment: Turns out that in Sandbox mode you only get the last 20 posts. Once approved, you are able to retrieve all posts from a user's account.

Answer (score 19):

I've solved this issue with the optional parameter count set to -1.

Comment: Using count=-1 actually causes a `504 Gateway Time-out` to occur, according to my tests.

Comment: count -1 actually gives 1 less result

Comment: i lost caption value and others with count -1.

Comment: This did work for me for about a month, but now it's no longer working. API return code 200 with no data.

Comment: @RonyVarghese that's not true. [-1] in indexation refers to the last element, so it will count until the last element. Do not say stupid things when you don't know.

Comment: @RonyVarghese other thing is whether it works or not, but that comment is totally irrelevant and unnecessary.

Answer (score 7):

It was a problem in [Instagram Developer Console](https://www.instagram.com/developer/). `max_id` and `min_id` doesn't work there.

Answer (score 5):

See http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/ for information on `pagination`. You need to subsequentially step through the result pages, each time requesting the next part with the `next_url` that the result specifies in the `pagination` object.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, this is it, but in the console you can get only last some elements. Max and min ofset don't work in the console. At least it was onehalf year ago.

Comment: Running the endpoint in March 2016 returns an empty pagination object. It looks like it is no longer supported. But can't find any official explanation as to why or if it should be possible to get a user's entire feed through the api.

Comment: Indeed pagination seems to be empty for the users media recent endpoint. But the new Instagram documentation (17 Nov 2015) explicitly says that "_Data is restricted to sandbox users and the 20 most recent media from each sandbox user_"

Comment: And also "_the API behaves as if the only users on Instagram were your sandbox users, and the only media ever posted were the last 20 for each of these users._", so I guess that pagination is empty due to this restriction, and that in production mode it will work just fine.

Answer (score 5):

In June 2016 Instagram made most of the functionality of their API available only to applications that have passed a review process. They still however provide JSON data through the web interface, and you can add the parameter `__a=1` to a URL to only include the JSON data.

```
max=
while :;do
  c=$(curl -s "https://www.instagram.com/username/?__a=1&max_id=$max")
  jq -r '.user.media.nodes[]?|.display_src'<<<"$c"
  max=$(jq -r .user.media.page_info.end_cursor<<<"$c")
  jq -e .user.media.page_info.has_next_page<<<"$c">/dev/null||break
done
```

Edit: As mentioned in the comment by alnorth29, the `max_id` parameter is now ignored. Instagram also changed the format of the response, and you need to perform additional requests to get the full-size URLs of images in the new-style posts with multiple images per post. You can now do something like this to list the full-size URLs of images on the first page of results:

```
c=$(curl -s "https://www.instagram.com/username/?__a=1")
jq -r '.graphql.user.edge_owner_to_timeline_media.edges[]?|.node|select(.__typename!="GraphSidecar").display_url'<<<"$c"
jq -r '.graphql.user.edge_owner_to_timeline_media.edges[]?|.node|select(.__typename=="GraphSidecar")|.shortcode'<<<"$c"|while read l;do
  curl -s "https://www.instagram.com/p/$l?__a=1"|jq -r '.graphql.shortcode_media|.edge_sidecar_to_children.edges[]?.node|.display_url'
done
```

To make a list of the shortcodes of each post made by the user whose profile is opened in the frontmost tab in Safari, I use a script like this:

```
sjs(){ osascript -e'{on run{a}','tell app"safari"to do javascript a in document 1',end} -- "$1";}

while :;do
  sjs 'o="";a=document.querySelectorAll(".v1Nh3 a");for(i=0;e=a[i];i++){o+=e.href+"\n"};o'>>/tmp/a
  sjs 'window.scrollBy(0,window.innerHeight)'
  sleep 1
done
```

Comment: Looks like the max_id parameter is now ignored on this endpoint.

Answer (score 4):

What I had to do is (in Javascript) is go through all pages by using a recursive function. It's dangerouse as instagram users could have thousands of pictures i a part from that (so your have to controle it) I use this code: (count parameter I think , doesn't do much)

```
        instagramLoadDashboard = function(hash)
    {
        code = hash.split('=')[1];

        $('#instagram-pictures .images-list .container').html('').addClass('loading');


        ts = Math.round((new Date()).getTime() / 1000);
        url = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent?count=200&min_timestamp=0&max_timestamp='+ts+'&access_token='+code;

        instagramLoadMediaPage(url, function(){

            galleryHTML = instagramLoadGallery(instagramData);
            //console.log(galleryHTML);
            $('#instagram-pictures .images-list .container').html(galleryHTML).removeClass('loading');
            initImages('#instagram-pictures');

            IGStatus = 'loaded';

        });

    };

    instagramLoadMediaPage = function (url, callback)
    {
        $.ajax({
                url : url,
                dataType : 'jsonp',
                cache : false,
                success:  function(response){

                                        console.log(response);

                                        if(response.code == '400')
                                        {
                                            alert(response.error_message);
                                            return false;
                                        }

                                        if(response.pagination.next_url !== undefined) {
                                            instagramData = instagramData.concat(response.data);
                                            return instagramLoadMediaPage(response.pagination.next_url,callback);
                                        }

                                        instagramData = instagramData.concat(response.data);
                                        callback.apply();
                                    }
        });
    };

    instagramLoadGallery = function(images)
    {
        galleryHTML ='<ul>';

        for(var i=0;i<images.length;i++)
        {
            galleryHTML += '<li><img src="'+images[i].images.thumbnail.url+'" width="120" id="instagram-'+images[i].id+' data-type="instagram" data-source="'+images[i].images.standard_resolution.url+'" class="image"/></li>';

        }

        galleryHTML +='</ul>';

        return galleryHTML;
    };
```

There some stuff related to print out a gallery of picture.

Comment: awesome, copy your js code and convert it into php, its work for me, good work victor

Answer (score 4):

Use the best recursion function for getting all posts of users.

```
<?php
    set_time_limit(0);
    function getPost($url,$i) 
    {
        static $posts=array();  
        $json=file_get_contents($url);
        $data = json_decode($json);
        $ins_links=array();
        $page=$data->pagination;
        $pagearray=json_decode(json_encode($page),true);
        $pagecount=count($pagearray);

        foreach( $data->data as $user_data )
        {
            $posts[$i++]=$user_data->link;
        }

        if($pagecount>0)
            return getPost($page->next_url,$i);
        else
            return $posts;
    }
    $posts=getPost("https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/CLIENT-ACCOUNT-NUMBER/media/recent?client_id=CLIENT-ID&count=33",0);

    print_r($posts);

?>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can user pagination of Instagram PHP API: https://github.com/cosenary/Instagram-PHP-API/wiki/Using-Pagination

Something like that:

```
    $Instagram = new MetzWeb\Instagram\Instagram(array(
        "apiKey"      => IG_APP_KEY,
        "apiSecret"   => IG_APP_SECRET,
        "apiCallback" => IG_APP_CALLBACK
    ));
    $Instagram->setSignedHeader(true);

    $pictures = $Instagram->getUserMedia(123);
    do {

        foreach ($pictures->data as $picture_data):

            echo '<img src="'.$picture_data->images->low_resolution->url.'">';

        endforeach;

    } while ($pictures = $instagram->pagination($pictures));
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `next_url` object to get the next 20 images.

In the JSON response there is an `pagination` array:

```
 "pagination":{
      "next_max_tag_id":"1411892342253728",
      "deprecation_warning":"next_max_id and min_id are deprecated for this endpoint; use min_tag_id and max_tag_id instead",
      "next_max_id":"1411892342253728",
      "next_min_id":"1414849145899763",
      "min_tag_id":"1414849145899763",
      "next_url":"https:\/\/api.instagram.com\/v1\/tags\/lemonbarclub\/media\/recent?client_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\u0026max_tag_id=1411892342253728"
 }
```

This is the information on specific API call and the object `next_url` shows the URL to get the next 20 pictures so just take that URL and call it for the next 20 pictures.

For more information about the Instagram API check out this blogpost: [Getting Friendly With Instagram’s API](https://medium.com/@KevinMcAlear/getting-friendly-with-instagrams-api-abe3b929bc52)

Answer (score 0):

Instagram developer console has provided the solution for it. https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/

To use this in PHP, here is the code snippet,

```
/**
**
** Add this code snippet after your first curl call
** assume the response of the first call is stored in $userdata
** $access_token have your access token
*/

$maximumNumberOfPost = 33; // it can be 20, depends on your instagram application
$no_of_images = 50 // Enter the number of images you want

if ($no_of_images > $maximumNumberOfPost) {

    $ImageArray = [];
    $next_url = $userdata->pagination->next_url;
    while ($no_of_images > $maximumNumberOfPost) {
           $originalNumbersOfImage = $no_of_images;
           $no_of_images = $no_of_images - $maximumNumberOfPost;
           $next_url = str_replace("count=" . $originalNumbersOfImage, "count=" . $no_of_images, $next_url);
           $chRepeat = curl_init();
           curl_setopt_array($chRepeat, [
                             CURLOPT_URL => $next_url,
                             CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
                                    "Authorization: Bearer $access_token"
                              ],
                              CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true
                            ]);
            $userRepeatdata = curl_exec($chRepeat);
            curl_close($chRepeat);
            if ($userRepeatdata) {
                      $userRepeatdata = json_decode($userRepeatdata);
                      $next_url = $userRepeatdata->pagination->next_url;
                     if (isset($userRepeatdata->data) && $userRepeatdata->data) {
                          $ImageArray = $userRepeatdata->data;
                   }
           }
    }

}
```