# Get all media instagram. More than 33 picture

Tags: api, media, instagram, getusermedia

I am trying to use Instagram API to create a gallery with all my instagram pictures.
But I have just 33 pictures in the gallery. Can you help me please?

```
    $media = $instagram->getUserMedia($userId);

    public function getUserMedia($id = 'self', $limit = 0) {
    return $this->_makeCall('users/' . $id . '/media/recent', ($id === 'self'), array('count' => $limit));
```

Kind regards.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Look here: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10881511/instagram-api-how-to-get-all-user-media>


That might help,Thanks.

Comment: i try to display more than 33 pictures in the gallery, but i can't, i have just 33 picture with no parameter count in getUserMedia function. the optional parameter count -1 is not working.

Comment: I have same issue, is there any update about this problem?

Answer (score -1):

Pass your desired count of images to the recent media endpoint:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/%USER%/media/recent/?count=%MAX_COUNT%&AccessTokenOrClientID
```

In the response you will get a `pagination` containing a `next_url` value which you can use to fetch the next part until you receive no more `next_url`s in the response.

Comment: please ,can you tell me how I can do this with php

Comment: At the moment, Instagram returns no more than 33 results per call

Comment: I did not say you can get more than 33 result per call, I just mentioned the `count` parameter and the use of pagination to get all the images and following calls.