# Instagram API: how can I get all user's pictures?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I am trying to use Instagram API to create a gallery with all user's instagram pictures. 
But I have just about 33 pictures in the gallery. 
Can you help me please? How can I fix this?

```
   $response = file_get_contents('https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/' . $target . '/media/recent?access_token=' . $_SESSION['instagram_token'] . '&count=-1');
```

Comment: What problem are you experiencing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Instagram API: How to get all user media?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10881511/instagram-api-how-to-get-all-user-media)

Answer (score 1):

According to [documentation](http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/) you are using an endpoint which will return all **recent** media from the user. Thus it does not promise to return **all** images. Even though you specify a count, there is a maximum number of images returned.

However, you can use pagination; see the following question/answer for information:

[Instagram API: How to get all user media?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10881511/instagram-api-how-to-get-all-user-media)

I suppose you can read 20 per request, then find the lowest id of the result and use this as the max id of the next request.

```
Request 1 (no max_id)
Id 100
Id 99
..
Id 81

Request 2 (max_id=81)
Id 80
.. 
Id 61

Request 3 (max_id=61)
Id 60
..
Id 41
```

Then keep requesting until you do not get any more media returned

Comment: it doesn't work. The result is the same as using the provided pagination.

Answer (score 0):

Each API call will return maximum of 20 photos, you have to use the `pagination.url` in the API response to make another API call to get next 20 photos and so on.

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/3/media/recent/?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```

Answer (score 0):

The Instagram API imposes a silent, undocumented limit on how many results it returns. Even if you pass in a `count` higher than `33`, it will only return, at most, 33 results.

I have written a [hack](https://github.com/d4nyll/instafetch/) in Javascript which eliminates this limit at the cost of making more API calls. At the moment, it only works if you query by user, but I can implement it so it works for queries by tag too, depending on my available time and demand.

Feel free to contribute by submitting pull requests! (You may want to translate what I did to PHP code so you can securely use the access token)