# What exactly are the parameters for Instagram's endpoint: /tags/tag-name/media/recent

Tags: python, instagram

I notice the Python library for Instagram and the API are a bit different.

The API request from documentation:

```
/tags/tag-name/media/recent
```

Found at: https://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/tags/

That page says 3 parameters:

> COUNT:    Count of tagged media to return.
>
> MIN_TAG_ID:   Return media before this min_tag_id.
>
> MAX_TAG_ID:   Return media after this max_tag_id.

My code:

```
recent_media, next_ = api.tag_recent_media(50, 10000, "cars")
```

The library documentation: https://github.com/Instagram/python-instagram

Documented syntax:

> api.tag_recent_media(count, max_tag_id, tag_name)

The problems:

1. Regardless of how big of `count` I put in, it always returns 33. I see nothing about 33 on the limits page: https://instagram.com/developer/limits/
2. Regardless of the `max_tag_id` I use, it has no effect.

Answer (score 1):

While the Python library only had itself [marked as unmaintained](https://github.com/facebookarchive/python-instagram/commit/6522cffe19065d456ceb0d10b0cd1a13c5026380) fairly recently, most of the commits leading up to the date of your question were either trivial or only impacted the [examples/README](https://github.com/facebookarchive/python-instagram/commits/master).

Yes, the `count` parameter appears to be limited, despite the lack of documentation, at 33. Apparently, some Instagram API endpoints [used to accept -1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14586216/833881) and return all relevant media, though this was removed/corrected quite a while ago.

Also, thanks to the new algorithmic timeline (which is indeed applied to this endpoint, which I was attempting to use for work), you are likely to receive results that have seen recent activity but are years old. I've gotten results from 2013 in my first batch of 33 for at least one tag.

The only parameter I've found useful on that endpoint is `count`, though as you've seen, you can only get a minor bump in returned data.

I suggest just sticking with the [`requests` library](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) for accessing IG's API from Python. For pagination, you can use the `next_url` value in the `pagination` dictionary (it's not present if there's no next page), without having to pass any extra parameters or attempting to deal with the obnoxiously obtuse `*_tag_id` parameters.

Basic API usage with `requests`:

```
import requests

response = requests.get(
    url='https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/{tagname}/media/recent'.format(tagname='testing'),
    params={
        'access_token': YOUR_TOKEN,
        'count': 33,
    }
).json()
```