# How to count number of Instagram media user liked?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

Currently I use `/users/self/media/liked` method, get the response, read `next_max_like_id` and request the data again and again. I've tried to pass huge `count` value, but looks like max count value is just `30`.
I need to track changes in the number of media user liked. Is there any way to optimize it? I don't understand well what `next_max_like_id` means? Is there any way to keep it and use it next time somehow?

Answer (score 5):

The request limit for `users/self/media/likes` is 33 (default is 20). The `next_url` that's returned in the pagination section will grab the chronologically preceding liked items, using the same `count` (if you've supplied one) and `next_max_like_id`, which is the id of the last result returned.

If by "track changes" you mean keep a running tally, as far as I know you can't access the total number of liked items via an endpoint. You'd have to write a script that scrapes like history, using the paginination info to jump backwards until you can see you've hit the original like by catching on a duplicate `next_max_like_id` (side note: the data returned only includes posts that the user still has access to).

If you have a lot of users, you'll have to stagger your queries with a cron job for the original scrape since there's a limit of 5000 API calls per hour. Once that's complete you could have a `last_id_liked` field in your database for continued count maintenance.

The only optimization I can offer is instead of counting returned results you can count the number of times you jump backwards and multiply by the count... but you're still using up an API call each time.

Answer (score 0):

**next_max_like_id** is for paginating to next set of likes data. You have to pass it to your next consecutive request. As Instagram API returning limited results, you can use this facility.

Comment: Thanks, but how does it answer my question? 

And, there is no any relation between 30 API calls per hours and 30 results returned in reply to the single call.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. Almost same issue here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10881511/instagram-api-how-to-get-all-user-media](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10881511/instagram-api-how-to-get-all-user-media) and seems like there is a limit to results to and you have to use pagination for getting next results set using `next_max_like_id` passing to next request.