# What is the total number of images we can fetch per public profile from instagram

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

1. What is the total number of images we can fetch per public profile
2. If its only 200 like instagram, can we iteratively do it?
3. Can we get the timestamp for each image fetched

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. What is the total number of images we can fetch per public profile

> you can fetch all photos using api

2. If its only 200 like instagram, can we iteratively do it?

> you can get 20 images per api call, and u can use `pagination` in api
>   to iteratively get next set of 20

3. Can we get the timestamp for each image fetched

> all photos have `created_time` in api response which has timestamp

Answer (score 1):

**You can also check below link**

> [Instagram API: How to get all user media?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10881511/instagram-api-how-to-get-all-user-media#answer-13728092)

Comment: The API has changed since Nov 2015