# Instagram API Pagination is not Working Properly

Tags: c#, instagram, instagram-api

as refer [Instagram API: How to get all user media?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10881511/instagram-api-how-to-get-all-user-media) 
 get pagination data with

```
 /v1/users/self/media/recent?count=-1&access_token=xxx.
```

it returns 20 photos because of limit and  also got pagination data

```
{"pagination": {"next_url": "http://....", "next_max_id": "841771651284233931_1369704762"}
```

now i pass this in next_max_id to fetch another 20 photos

```
/v1/users/self/media/recent?access_token=xxx&max_id="841771651284233931_1369704762"
```

get only 1 photo and with no pagination data

```
{"pagination": {}, "meta": {"code": 200}, "data":
```

There are 29 photos in my instagram, so 20 photos in one api call and in another call only 1 photo is retrieved, what about others and what to do?

Comment: is your url same as `next_url` ?? `next_url` usually works great, why dont u just use that ?

Comment: i am using same url as mentioned in next_url but for second call that give me only 1 pic not another 8 photos

Comment: what is your username?, will check on https://www.picodash.com

Comment: my username is @hiral_bhimani 
i already told my pagination is not work so in that manner i want solution