# How can I get all my instagram account feed?

Tags: api, instagram, instagram-api

I'm trying to get all my instagram account feeds/images. But I found that the api has restriction for 20 feeds only. I can only get my latest 20 posts. But I want all my posts/feeds. I guess there is some way to do that cause I found some examples that is displaying all the feeds.

Any suggestions can be helpful. Thank you in adcance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Instagram API: How to get all user media?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10881511/instagram-api-how-to-get-all-user-media)

Answer (score 2):

If you just signed up for API, you will be in Sandbox mode which has limitations

> The behavior of the API when you are in sandbox mode is the same as
>   when your app is live, but comes with the following restrictions:
>
> - Data is restricted to sandbox users and the 20 most recent media from each sandbox user
> - Reduced API rate limits

more info here: https://www.instagram.com/developer/sandbox/

Answer (score 0):

Use have to submit request to instagram. Example for your case you can submit basic permission to read a user’s profile info and media. Step by step:
 1. Create new client at https://www.instagram.com/developer/
 2. Make video screencast of your app to tell how you use the permission
 3. Go to manage tab -> permission tab and submit to instagram approval