# how to show max page image in instagram.com?& take json

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, instagram

i want to take a json code from instagram.com. please see:
http://www.instagram.com/meysamtalebi590/?__a=1

^^^but this link only show 12 of first medias^^^

with click on "load more" link can see all of medias

but not be abale to take json@@

how i can to take json for all medias?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Instagram API: How to get all user media?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10881511/instagram-api-how-to-get-all-user-media)

Comment: no i want work only with his username           this work with token

Comment: Yes you need to use the API if you want all the media, you can't do it with your method

Comment: @MeysamTalebi Unrelated question ! are you using instagram api's in sandbox mode  or live mode ? i have some question from you if you are using live mode . thanks