# Give All user media from instagram

Tags: php, instagram-api

I'm Trying to Give user All media from instagram with this code in Guzzle:

```
 $res = $client->request('GET', 
'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?access_token='. 
 $access_token);
```

But Instagram send me just 20 media.How I can fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Instagram API: How to get all user media?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10881511/instagram-api-how-to-get-all-user-media)

Comment: @Dalton How I can Add count after access_token Variable in my code?

Answer (score 1):

See this link to solve your problem:

[Instagram API: How to get all user media?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10881511/instagram-api-how-to-get-all-user-media)

You have to use pagination, getting 20 objects per time.

Comment: before I asked this question read this link But I don't Know How Add max_id in my code.Can you help me?

Comment: Please read all the answers and comments in the link. There are some suggestions there about this.

Comment: Also note that if you are in sandbox mode you will only get 20 items, pagination will not work