# how to get all media of an instagaram user account without access_token?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I have to fetch all photos and videos of a public user in instagram and download them in my android app.

I used `https://api.instagram.com/<username>/media/` before and it worked fine. But now I cant use this to get media of users and it does not work. 
So I found `https://www.instagram.com/<username>/?__a=1`, it works fine. 
But it cant get video files. Does any body know how can I get all user media?

example: https://www.instagram.com/ibm/?__a=1

Comment: Not sure if that is possible. But mind you the above `__a=1` url gives only recent ones. does not support pagination or can retrieve full media

Comment: @enator , whats your idea about getting all media?. also by `__a=1` we can use `&max_id=?` in url to pagination.

Comment: No. for all media have to go via API and auth flow. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10881511/instagram-api-how-to-get-all-user-media?rq=1